# Find the top left origin of a GroupBox's inner area

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, layout, groupbox

I know the `GroupBox` is almost like a `Panel` with a header and a border but is not scrollable.

So in the `GroupBox` there is what I call the "**inner area**" where we want the inner elements to be displayed.

But it seems that the `GroupBox` does not place the elements in this area but directly at its top left corner like would a dumb panel.

Here is a simple illustration of the "issue":

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Button button = new Button { Text = "Hello!!!" };

        GroupBox groupBox = new GroupBox { Text = "Some useful stuff", Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
        groupBox.Controls.Add(button);

        this.Controls.Add(groupBox);
    }
}
```

Which gives this ugly result:

[image: GroupBox with Button inside]

I could play with the `Button`'s `Location` property to add an offset but this is not 100% satisfactory.

What is the cleanest way to place the elements "inside the inner area"?

Is there a way to know the size of the border and header in order to use the right offset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the GroupBox's DisplayRectangle property for that:

```
Button button = new Button { Text = "Hello!!!" };
button.Location = groupBox.DisplayRectangle.Location;
groupBox.Controls.Add(button);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick and accurate answer. Seems to do the job. :) It's a shame it's not correctly documented and that you are even discouraged from using it because "This API supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code.".